# EU countries with registered partnership option

Tags: visa, working-visas, eu-citizens, europe, non-residents

I'm a non-EU citizen man with a long term non-EU girlfriend.

We both want to move to Europe together. We both speak English well. I'm a skilled software developer so i'm fairly confident about my plan of finding a job which provides me a working visa - sponsorship. Unfortunately her profession isn't in shortage of workers in Europe (she's a HR specialist).

In which European countries i can find a job and bring her with me as my registered partner with working permit without getting married ? I've heard Netherlands provides that, can you name any other countries please ?

I've searched it online a lot but couldn't find any information for non-EU citizens. If you just give me what keywords to search, that'ld help me a lot as well.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I would vote to close this as "too broad".  *Where* in Europe do you want to go?  (A country other than your own is probably going to be easier.)

Comment: @MartinBonner anywhere in Europe, other than mine.

Comment: @Emre Acar Is there a shortage of software developers in every European country? You’d probably get a better answer(s) if you narrowed down your target countries. As it stands, your question may be closed as ‘too broad’.

Comment: @Traveller yes, there is shortage of software developers in every European country. Name one which isn't please (except Vatican lol).

Comment: Note that in some EU countries, "registered partnership" is the official same-sex alternative to marriage. Can you explain why you want to become "registered partners" while getting married is not an option?

Comment: @TooTea I love my girlfriend but i'm not ready to get married. Do i really have to get interrogated about this ?

Comment: @EmreAcar No, of course not. I just wanted to point out that it may not be possible to enter into an "registered partnership" with a woman in some countries, which will limit your options. (And even if it was, the procedure for dissolving a registered partnership is essentially the same as getting a divorce.)

Comment: @TooTea Well this is what my question is. Which countries can i enter with a woman ?

Comment: @EmreAcar Take a look at this [map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Civil_Unions_map_Europe.png). You're out of luck in the dark green and grey countries.

Comment: @TooTea Thank you. Can you add this as an answer so i can award you with the bounty ?

Comment: But it doesn't answer your question. I don't have the slightest idea about the relevant visa/work permit rules for each of the countries. I'm hoping someone else does.

Comment: @TooTea If they accept us as partners in blue countries, they should let her stay and work as well, right ?

Comment: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/family/couple/registered-partners/index_en.htm, the Wikipedia map is wrong unfortunately – at least for my country

Comment: Anyway I agree with @MartinBonner, first decide on a country, I'd either decide based on salary (Switzerland, UK...) or climate (Spain, Portugal), and if it's not suitable then research the next preferred one. Language is also important, for example speaking English well might not mean much to employers in France

Comment: As a British citizen, can I suggest *not* UK?  The Home Office (Government department responsible for immigration among other things) has an official policy of operating a "hostile environment" for illegal immigrants, and legal immigrants get caught up in this.  Scandinavia, Netherlands, Switzerland, Berlin, Munich (the rest of Germany less so) all seem like better choices.